# Ajax is not working. It doesn't show any error

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter-3

I used Ajax in my application. Previously it woks very fine and checked many times. Now is not working. I didn't change anything in this code.

I checked URL path and I also checked Jquery click  event.

It doesn't shows any error in the console log.

```
$(".submit").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var month = $("#month").val();
    var zone = $("#zone").val();    
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '<?php echo base_url().'index.php/ContMain/generate'; ?>',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {month: month, zone: zone},
      success: function(res) {  
         alert(res);
      }

   });
});
```

Comment: Your response is probably empty

Comment: Check what is the response from php

Comment: Yeah I checked. Now I understand

Comment: pls tell what was the problem

Comment: Its Json error. Response is empty

Comment: Use - `site_url('/ContMain/generate')` - so `index.php` is automatically added if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use chrome to access the page, and press **F12** then tab to the **Netwrok** Panel.
2. Make sure **Request URL** is valid, **Status Code** equals 200, and **Request Headers** is valid.

[image]

3. Code like this to show the result or error

```html
<script>
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/ContMain/generate'; ?>",
    dataType: 'json ', 
    data: {
      month: month, 
      zone: zone
     }, 
     success: function(res) { 
      console.log('success', res);
     },
     error: function(err) {
      console.log('error', err);
     }
   );
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks.Your answer is very helpful to find the error in which place.